# Why does hyperlink jump with offset at destination?

Tags: beamer, labels, hyperlink

I use hyperlinks and labels in beamer to jump across frames.
Usually I want to jump to the beginning of a frame, as in the example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[t,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\useoutertheme{infolines} %broader lines than Malmoe standard
\usetheme{Luebeck} %Malmoe/Luebeck inverts colours in headers and title 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hyperlink{NV}{goto next slide}
\item \hyperlink{NV2}{goto third slide}
\item \hyperlink{NV3}{goto last slide}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{center}
next...
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[label=NV]{Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item this is the first line below the title
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm} 
\begin{center}
 next...
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[label=NV2]{Title 2}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item this is the first line below the title
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm} 
\begin{center}
 next...
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[label=NV3]{Title 3}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item this is the first line below the title
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm} 
\begin{center}
 end
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

When I run the pdf-output as a presentation (with evince or okular), or on full-screen mode, by clicking on the hyperlink, the output jumps to the beginning of the frame with the corresponding label.
When running the same file on a window (NOT full screen), the jump goes to the second line of the frame. This is unwanted behaviour. I cannot recall this happened before 2021.

Why does the "jump" function behave differently?
Thanks,
M. Natiello

Comment: I don't think that anything changed here. The destination is a bit below the top border in texlive 2020 too. In my viewers it is only a problem if the pdf is zoomed to a size larger than the  window.  You could use `\hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}` to force the pdf to fit the window.  (Btw: How a pdf viewer handles links in full screen mode is not something hyperref can control, typically they ignore destination instructions like anchor coordinates and always use Fit).

Comment: Yes! That instruction solves my issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that anything changed here. The destination is a bit below the top border in texlive 2020 too. In my viewers it is only a problem if the pdf is zoomed to a size larger than the window.

You can use

```
  \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}
```

to force the pdf to fit the window when you jump to a destination.

Side remark: How a pdf viewer handles links in full screen mode is not something hyperref can control, typically they ignore destination instructions like anchor coordinates and always use `Fit`.